# Chrome contenteditable caret alignment

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a problem in using contenteditable for Chrome. I used the contenteditable property on the onmouseover event of span with some padding. When the span is focused (editing), the caret is aligned to the bottom border of the span when tested in Chrome, it is fine on Firefox.

HTML

```
<div>
    Some <span onmouseover="this.contentEditable=true;">Editable</span> Text
</div>
```

CSS

```
[contenteditable]:focus {
    background: rgba(255,220,0,0.3);
    padding: 10px;
}
```

Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ZE8mn/)

Thank you for any help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `display: inline-block` to span

```
[contenteditable]:focus {
    background: rgba(255,220,0,0.3);
    padding: 10px; 
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, but is there no other way to fix it? because I need those span elements inline.

Comment: `display: inline-block` to the rescue!